# WPF why methodInfo = object.GetType().GetMethod("SelectionChanged") ..... return a null value?

Tags: c#, wpf

I have a form in wpf , at runtime in the Load event add the following controls from XAML string

```
// load Canvas
sXAML = "<Canvas  xmlns='http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation' xmlns:x='http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml'";            
sXAML += " Height=\"Auto\" Name=\"canvasMain\" Width=\"Auto\">";
sXAML += " </Canvas>";

XmlDocument xdoc = new XmlDocument();
xdoc.LoadXml(sXAML);
XmlTextReader xmlReader = new XmlTextReader(new StringReader(xdoc.OuterXml));
object obj = XamlReader.Load(xmlReader);

if (obj != null)
{
 Canvas cnv = obj as Canvas;
 this.AddChild(cnv);
        this.RegisterName(cnv.Name, cnv);
}
```

then add a Canvas a dataGrid control

```
// load dataGrid             
sXAML = "<DataGrid xmlns='http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation' xmlns:x='http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml'";
sXAML += " AutoGenerateColumns=\"True\" Height=\"207\" HorizontalAlignment=\"Left\" Margin=\"140,6,0,0\" Name=\"dtgListServer\" VerticalAlignment=\"Top\" Width=\"751\" AlternatingRowBackground=\"LightCyan\">";
sXAML += "</DataGrid>";

XmlDocument xdoc = new XmlDocument();
xdoc.LoadXml(sXAML);
XmlTextReader xmlReader = new XmlTextReader(new StringReader(xdoc.OuterXml));
object obj = XamlReader.Load(xmlReader);

if (obj != null)
{
 DataGrid dtg = obj as DataGrid;
        cnv.Children.Add(dtg);
        cnv.RegisterName(dtg.Name, dtg);
}
```

I must now add events to DataGrid  control , but the method GetMethod always returns null

```
EventInfo ei = dtg.GetType().GetEvent(eventname);
MethodInfo mi = dtg.GetType().GetMethod(methodname, BindingFlags.Public | BindingFlags.Instance | BindingFlags.NonPublic);
Delegate del = Delegate.CreateDelegate(ei.EventHandlerType, this, mi);
ei.AddEventHandler(dtg, del);
```

of course I tried with the method "SelectionChanged" and more flag but the result is always null
anyone can help me and indicate where is my mistake
I thank you in advance

Answer (score 1):

`SelectionChanged` is another event, not a method; you can't treat it like a method and have the first event call into the second. Perhaps you mean the (non-public) [`OnSelectionChanged`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc838787.aspx)? (you would need to specify `BindingFlags.Instance | BindingFlags.NonPublic`)

Comment: first thank you for your reply.
Is only recently that I use C#.
What I need is to add an event to a control added at runtime.
For this I found

EventInfo ei = dtg.GetType().GetEvent(eventname);

Then I create a Delegate

Delegate del = Delegate.CreateDelegate(ei.EventHandlerType, .............);

to add an event handler

ei.AddEventHandler(dtg, del);

my ignorance is to create the delegate for an event

Comment: @cesare - if you write what you mean in *regular* c#, I will translate to reflection for you.

Comment: first thank you for your reply. 
Is only recently that I use C#. 
What I need is to add an event to a control added at runtime. 
For this I found
DataGrid dtg = obj as DataGrid; 
EventInfo ei = dtg.GetType().GetEvent(eventname); Then 
I create a Delegate 
Delegate del = Delegate.CreateDelegate(ei.EventHandlerType, this, mi);
to add an event handler 
ei.AddEventHandler(dtg, del);
but Delegate.CreateDelegate use 
MethodInfo mi = this.GetType().GetMethod(methodname, BindingFlags.NonPublic);
my problem is to create the delegate for an event not for a Method